# KMP Module in Android Project

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

Is it possible to create a KMP module and add it to an android project as a separate module ?
If it is possible, how can I do so ?

I tried to create one but the android studio does not seem to find the KMP module.

The error I get is:
`Could not resolve project :orderingKmm. Required by: project :app`

Comment: Did you forget to add your `orderingKmm` module to your `settings.gradle.kts` file?

Comment: No, It is added to the settings file.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not that it can't find your KMP module.

It can actually find the `:orderingKmm`.

But the problem is that the `:orderingKmm` can't build properly or resolve the project properly.

There is a possibility that you did not add the necessary plugin to build the KMP module.

Have you added the necessary plugin in your **main** `build.gradle` script?

Ex.

```
alias(libs.plugins.kotlinMultiplatform) appy false
```

or below, if you do not have `libs.versions.toml` yet. (I recommend you use libs.versions.toml)

```
classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin.multiplatform:1.9.22"
```

Another way you can do is to create a Kotlin Multiplatform project instead.

And add your android module. This way, you are sure that the Kotlin Multiplatform project is working properly.